# Basic Texas Hold'em Rules Clarification

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

I'm trying to learn the rules for Texas Hold'em, and the different rules I've been reading online left me with the following questions unanswered:

1. In pre-flop, do the small blind and big blind players take a turn after all other players have had their turn? (Or does betting blind count as their turn)
2. At the end of every street (i.e. just before a card reveal/showdown), must all players bet the same amount in order to proceed to the next street? (For example, if the last player in the round raised, must all other players compare their bet or fold?)

Answer (score 3):

1. Everyone gets to act pre-flop, regardless of their position. (Blinds don't count as actions). Of course, If someone has been put all-in because of paying the blind, they can't act, but they will stay in the hand until showdown. If everyone folds (including Small Blind) and you are the Big Blind, you will automatically win the pot and the hand is over.
2. All the players who want to stay in the hand and see the next card, need to be equally committed to the pot. (unless they are all-in and can't match the original bet-size, in which case they will stay in the hand until showdown/river, and win as much as they have committed to the pot)

A lot of your questions about the basics will be answered if you get some hands-on experience and play a few hands. (Online is the way to go. Although, I would start with play-money.)

Answer (score 0):

In short, 
1. Yes, they get a turn, and they can raise/check/fold as usual.
2. Yes, it will keep going until everyone still in the round calls.